# LDAP uniqueMember attribute not recognised in linux

Tags: linux, ldap, openldap, groups

I have an LDAP group with a groupOfUniqueNames objectclass and and an auxiliary posixGroup objectclass.

When I use the memberUid attribute the values (members of group) are recognised in linux. But with uniqueMember not.

In the ldap.conf of my ldap client there is the configuration:

> nss_schema    rfc2307bis

So I guess it should have worked since the rfc2307bis supports the uniqueMember value.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is in sssd.conf to change / add the following line:

`ldap_group_member = uniqueMember`

- Still searching though if I can use uniqueMember and memberUid (not only one of them) because I have groups with both attributes. But that's a different question I guess.